# 20.04 LTS OneDrive Issues Linking account

Tags: sync

I was able to get my OneDrive working about two weeks ago on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS OS. I was messing around and messed my OS up. So I decided to wipe and start fresh. When I was trying to set my laptop up again, my OneDrive was having issues and keeps pushing this code out. I was curious if anyone has ran into this issue before?

```
onedrive.OneDriveException@src/onedrive.d(874): HTTP request returned status code 400 (Bad Request)
{
    "correlation_id": "b9d141bf-d601-42e8-9b43-91fa1a9e62f2",
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_codes": [
        70000
    ],
    "error_description": "AADSTS70000: The provided value for the 'code' parameter is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: bb17a3b0-ac2a-4e31-96a9-f05574966600\r\nCorrelation ID: b9d141bf-d601-42e8-9b43-91fa1a9e62f2\r\nTimestamp: 2020-08-17 15:55:02Z",
    "error_uri": "https:\/\/login.microsoftonline.com\/error?code=70000",
    "timestamp": "2020-08-17 15:55:02Z",
    "trace_id": "bb17a3b0-ac2a-4e31-96a9-f05574966600"
}
----------------
??:? [0x5642287239d9]
??:? [0x564228722cb5]
??:? [0x564228723b65]
??:? [0x564228721f58]
??:? [0x5642287218c5]
??:? [0x56422872f7a8]
??:? void rt.dmain2._d_run_main2(char[][], ulong, extern (C) int function(char[][])*).runAll() [0x7fb49121c9db]
??:? _d_run_main2 [0x7fb49121c7ee]
??:? _d_run_main [0x7fb49121c65d]
??:? __libc_start_main [0x7fb490e080b2]
??:? [0x5642286fa5ed]
```

I click on the link, sign into my account and then copy the link and put it in the terminal. This was the output on the terminal after I clicked enter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I tried to install onedrive using `sudo apt install onedrive` and building it myself from the repository *https://github.com/skilion/onedrive*.
**BUT the 'skilion' repo was abandoned in 2018** and contains many defects.

**The latest and maintained code of onedrive for linux can be found here:** https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive. I followed the instructions from there and installed onedrive under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and now it works like a charm :)

Comment: Here are usefull URLs: [git repo with install intructions](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md) and [PPA Package](https://launchpad.net/~yann1ck/+archive/ubuntu/onedrive) - i testet it on Ubuntu ubuntu 20.04.1 and it works great.

Comment: No it doesn't. It is plauged by [this bug](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/issues/1092) and it is unfixable.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem for a long time, Then I find out that onedrive installed from the default ppa is quite old and installing it from the following ppa resolved the issue for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yann1ck/onedrive
sudo apt install onedrive
```

This is the developer created ppa 
[https://launchpad.net/~yann1ck/+archive/ubuntu/onedrive](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyann1ck/+archive/ubuntu/onedrive)

Comment: Please do not use this PPA - it contains obsolete client software. Please install the client from the correct location by following https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

To install the client correctly on Ubuntu please follow https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md

Do not follow any other instructions on the Internet or elsewhere